# Unreal Engine 4 depth of dying

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm developing a survival game and i need to increase the distance on the y axis that lets the character go down to a certain y axis before dying/disappearing in the game. So far it isn't working and its going to effect the game. If someone could help me that would be very great

Comment: The "depth of dying"? People can "go very low"? This question is lacking a lot of context. Have you considered visiting the official UE forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your map, open world settings (window->World Settings), Under the 'World' tab there's a Kill Z property. Hope that helps!